# Hide div after second animation CSS

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

I have a little problem in my code. I'm trying to make my text disappear after the second animation, which is the first animation in "div.textoe" (input text on the page) and the second animation is in the "div.textoee". What I want to do is clear the text of the page after the second animation, but it does not happen in my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
$(".textoe").on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(){ 
    $('.textoe').addClass('textoee'); 
    $('.textoee').removeClass('textoe'); 
}); 
$(".textoee").on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(){ 
    alert('Hide text');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w55dN/1/

Comment: why do you have those <br> in the code?

Comment: try $('.textoee').remove();

Comment: sorry man, i remove it.

Comment: Friend did not work, even by the fact that neither the alert to be working.

Comment: thats means your jquery is not working

Comment: My jquery is working, since it adds and removes the previous class, but not of the alert at the end of the animation of the second div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation since the class you want to target in the binding is added dynamically:

```
$(document).on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', '.textoee' ,function(){ 
    alert('Hide text');
});
```

Comment: This alert is functioning at the end of the first animation too, and that can not happen, because when I put .remove(), it will not perform the second animation.

Comment: @user2872499 can you provide a reproducible example of your issue? preferably in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @user2872499 It was alerting after the first animation because the event was bubbling up, to avoid that you can use event delegation in both functions ([see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/w55dN/4/)) or you can use a single function and check the class on the elmement ([demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/w55dN/3/))